# How does dependency uninstalls occur while uninstalling a software in OS?

Tags: installation, filesystems, operating-systems, uninstall, homebrew

I installed `mono` and using homebrew and its dependencies is installed with it as a prerequisite. After uninstalling the mono again I realized it does not uninstall dependencies it installed initially and we could run `brew autoremove` as an extra step.

Or another example is that, I installed `mono` for MacOS ventura by downloading `.pkg` and following GUI instructions.

> This README is for Mono.framework 6.12.0_182.
>
> This is the Mono Runtime and Development Platform
> (http://www.mono-project.com/).
>
> This package installs Mono and all of its dependencies inside of
> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework.

In this case, I am assuming following their uninstall instructions is enough since they install everything in the same directory.

> sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework

> sudo pkgutil --forget

> com.xamarin.mono-MDK.pkg sudo rm /etc/paths.d/mono-commands

My question is how does OS handles software dependency uninstalls? Do I need to store every dependency or whether developers installs everything in the same directory in order to uninstall it properly and do not have to worry about unused packages?

Comment: First of all.. one OS is not another.. and one package manager is not another.  Your question implies that they are related and they are not.  The OS has NOTHING to do with brew.  Last time I checked, Brew had an `autoremove` feature that would remove dependencies.  Fist uninstall package `A` .. then run `brew autoremove` to clean up unneeded dependencies.  It's been quite a while since using a mac but I seem to remember this is how it is done.

Comment: I was trying to imply the same point as you. Installing a package from website or homebrew have these two different approaches. Would someone expect every software developer or distributor do its own thing or there are some rules (not so strict apparently) around this issue.

Comment: Correct.. not so strict ;-) This is true for every package manager I know of but some are more strict than others.